# Change Ease of Access Settings via Windows API: SystemParametersInfo

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, settings, apimonitor

I am trying to toggle the three settings in Ease of Access via the `SystemParametersInfo` API call.

For example, I can turn off Show animations in Windows (1) like this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION, 0, (PVOID)false, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

And I can turn off the Show desktop background image (3) by calling:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDISABLEOVERLAPPEDCONTENT, 0, (PVOID)true, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

However, I cannot find how to toggle Show transparency in Windows (2).

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa

I have tried to monitor API calls using [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) but without success.  It shows the calls above but only calls to `SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST` when transparency is toggled.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image: Ease of Use Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I cannot find how to toggle Show transparency in Windows (2).

Change transparency option cause the following registry value change:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\EnableTransparency
```

`1`: On, `0`: Off

If it helps you can achieve the purpose via writing registry key.

**Note:** **Although it is possible technically, there is no official document about this. So it is not suggested to use in product environment.**

Comment: Thank you very much.  This does exactly what I wanted.  I had avoided registry changes as setting visual effects via registry keys does not seem to apply immediately.  However, not for this one!  It changes the behaviour right away.  Thanks again.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation doesn't have anything official on this particular registry key. Since you posted this from an account with an *"MSFT"* suffix can we assume that this is now the official way to change this system setting?